# How to print inline CSS styles?

Tags: css, printing, inline

is there a way to print css styles, that are inline?

I use this code to print part of the code:

```
w=window.open();
w.document.write($('#printable').html());
w.print();
w.close();
```

I could use external file and make it media=print, but part of the html are chars, that are generated by php and I could make it by making class for every posible outcome, but that would be pain.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: is it necessary to open a popup?

Comment: No, it's neccecery to print the <div id='printable'>

Comment: Would you clarify your goal? You say you are trying to separate out all the inline CSS styles from an HTML document and print them to a printer? Or you're just trying to do a sort of "Print Source" task that sends the entire HTML of a page to the printer for the user?

Comment: All I want is to print the selected div only. The way it is displayed in browser.

Comment: Please see my answer I gave you.

Answer (score 13):

See the Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/x69UY/

What do you think if you do like this:

```
<div id="printableDiv">
    <style type="text/css">
        @media print {
            #printable { 
               color: red; 
               // Any Other style you want to add 
             }
        }
    </style>
    <div id="printable">
        This Text will print in red color.
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript/jQuery code:

```
w=window.open();
w.document.write($('#printableDiv').html());
w.print();
w.close();
```

In this scenario while a popup opens and gets the HTML of `printableDiv`, the styles for printer will be included in that popup so the printer will read styles from popup and will print in that manner.

Comment: Well, there are 2 things, why I can't use this code. The main thing is, that this way I'd have to give class .noprintable to every element on the page, that I don't want to print, which is no possible. The second thing is, that it doesn't solve the problem, that I need to print the inline css.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, because i use instyle style to dynamically change background-color, and then the color was not in the print.
styleSheets[3] is my print.css file.

This worked for me:
I uncluded it in the smarty foreach i use to give some elements a background color.

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
  document.styleSheets[3].insertRule(" #caldiv_<?smarty $item.calendar_id ?> { border-color:<?smarty $item.color ?> }", 1);
</script>
```