# no border on HTML table when printing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on website that is supposed to print table.

One problem I'm running into is that some table borders won't be printed, although they are correctly displayed on screen.

I tried both Firefox and Chrome. Both display all table borders on screen, but omit some of the borders when printing.

What do I need to do to get them printed?

**EDIT 1: Added jsFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Ax4qU/

Code:

JavaScript:

```
function printDiv()
{
  var divToPrint=document.getElementById('table');
  newWin= window.open("");
  newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
  newWin.print();
  newWin.close();
}
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">

    html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    abbr, address, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
    small, strong, sub, sup, var,
    b, i,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        background: transparent;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font: 12px/15px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #555;
        background: #f5f5f5 url(bg.jpg);
    }

    a {
        color: #666;
    }

    #content {
        width: 65%;
        max-width: 690px;
        margin: 6% auto 0;
    }

    table {
        overflow: hidden
        border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
        background: #fefefe;
        width: 70%;
        margin: 5% auto 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px; /* FF1+ */
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* Saf3-4 */
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    th, td {
        padding: 18px 28px 18px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    th {
        padding-top: 22px;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
        background: #e8eaeb;
    }

    td {
        border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    }

    tr.odd-row td {
        background: #f6f6f6;
    }

    td.first, th.first {
        text-align: left
    }

    td.last {
        border-right: none;
    }

    /*
    Background gradients are completely unnecessary but a neat effect.
    */

    td {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 25% 90deg, #fefefe, #f9f9f9);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 25%, from(#f9f9f9), to(#fefefe));
    }

    tr.odd-row td {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 25% 90deg, #f6f6f6, #f1f1f1);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 25%, from(#f1f1f1), to(#f6f6f6));
    }

    th {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 20% 90deg, #e8eaeb, #ededed);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 20%, from(#ededed), to(#e8eaeb));
    }

    tr:first-child th.first {
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px; /* Saf3-4 */
    }

    tr:first-child th.last {
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px; /* Saf3-4 */
    }

    tr:last-child td.first {
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; /* Saf3-4 */
    }

    tr:last-child td.last {
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; /* Saf3-4 */
    }

</style>
```

Comment: When you are printing the DIV content in different window, are you sure those all css are also getting copied into that?

Comment: @KD . I think not. I open new window just to print table

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As the table is being copied to a new window, your CSS is not being retained. You can get around this by passing some relevant CSS across to the new window in your document.write() method. You also need to provide a small amount of padding to introduce the borders. See the following JSFiddle showing this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/826Zm/3/

```
function printDiv() {
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById('table');
    var htmlToPrint = '' +
        '<style type="text/css">' +
        'table th, table td {' +
        'border:1px solid #000;' +
        'padding:0.5em;' +
        '}' +
        '</style>';
    htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
}
```

Comment: This is very good. It works perfectly for any kind of table

Answer (score 3):

Try `window.print()` instead of `printDiv()` because you're not loading CSS.

or

updating your CSS to this

```
table {
    border: solid #000 !important;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px !important;
}
th, td {
    border: solid #000 !important;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0 !important;
}
```

or to this

```
@media print {
    table {
        border: solid #000 !important;
        border-width: 1px 0 0 1px !important;
    }
    th, td {
        border: solid #000 !important;
        border-width: 0 1px 1px 0 !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `!important` is a surefire way of bad CSS design. It should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @MikeK Thanks for the tip :) There are lots of things I wouldn't use in web but sometimes I just have - in order to make things working.

Answer (score 2):

I think this other SO question, [How to print inline CSS styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033340/how-to-print-inline-css-styles), might hold the answer to your question.

Another thing to try is setting your stylesheet using the standard `<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylefile.css" type="text/css" media="print" >` syntax so you specify one or more media targets (just separate them with a comma).

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the comment by "K D" it looks like you're not copying the CSS over to the new window. My guess is that you're doing it this way so only that specific table on the entire page is printed. There is an easier way to go about this, define a print stylesheet which negates every element except the one you want to print. No JavaScript and new windows and copying anything over is needed.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ref="myPrintStylesheet.css" type"text/css" media="print" />
```

myPrintStylesheet.css:

```
* {
    display: none;
}

#table {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but borders are not visible @MattK

Comment: Are you trying this on the same page and not in a separate window? Let's see your code.

Comment: I try it on same page and on same windows. I am using new tab to print table.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by using a new tab to print the table. It should all be on the same page, can you post what you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

So what worked for me was

```
<div style = 'background-color: white; width: 800PX; border-style: solid ; border-color:  black ; padding: 12px;  margin: 10px; 'class = box>
```

I used the style tag inside the div tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, replace YOUR.css with your link:

```
function printDiv() {
var strHtml = "<html>\n<head>\n <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"YOUR.css\">\n</head><body><div style=\"testStyle\">\n" + document.getElementById('table').innerHTML + "\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>";
newWin = window.open("");
newWin.document.writeln(strHtml);
newWin.print();
newWin.close();
}

document.getElementById('printbtn').addEventListener('click', printDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `table-layout: fixed;` fixed this issue for me. 
I ended up with something like below:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}
```