# Border radius rounded corners not showing up on print

Tags: html, css

I have read with interest [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576851/no-border-on-html-table-when-printing)

But this has not helped me understand why the problem of border-radius not showing up on print.

They display in the browser, but do not print.

HTML

```
<div class="card">

    <div class = "qr">
    <div id ="qr1"></div>
    <?php echo $_POST["url"]; ?>
    <div id ="qr2"></div>
    <div id ="qr3"></div>
    <div id ="qr4"></div>

    </div>

    <div class = "desc">
    <div>Site title</div>
    <div><?php echo $_POST["titleText"] ?></div>
    <div>Hosting site</div>
    <div><?php echo $_POST["hostText"] ?></div>
    <div>Who made this site?</div>
    <div><?php echo $_POST["orgText"] ?></div>
    <div>Other information</div>
    <div><?php echo $_POST["commentText"] ?></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.qr {
float:left;   
position: relative;
width: 30%;
}

.desc {
float:left;
width: 70%;
}

.card {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
border-top: 30px solid black;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
padding: 5px;
}
```

Everything I have read suggests I am doing this right. Any help spotting what I have missed would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the media settings for your CSS?

Comment: may try to create a pdf first and than print this...

Comment: @2C-B Elsewhere I have

    (at)media print {}

Which removes the background colour. But changing or removing this has no effect.

Comment: Pretty much all the articles I find related to borders not printing suggest that it relates to some error in the media value: either it is not defined for print media or there is some other problem in the specification of it. I would suggest focussing your attention on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borders and HRs are considered to be background-images, and so by default, will not print with your page. If you want to allow them to print, you will have to manually choose to print the page background.

I don't know where you find this setting on all browsers, but I know that in Chrome, the setting is in the print dialog. I would assume a similar location in other browsers.

[image]

---

Under "+More Settings" > "Options":

[image]