# css effects on iframe are not printed

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax, iframe

I am creating one program in which I have used iframe. I am applying css on iframe and it is working well on the browser. But when I try to print that iframe, css effect doesn't appear. I tried to print the iframe from IE, Chrome, Mozilia and Edge. But none of them is printing properly. Only some effects are shown on the page. Can anyone tell me the solution ?

Thank you :)

I have two files in my program. My code is following:

**createForm.php**

```
<?php

$clmns=$_REQUEST['clmns'];
$rows=$_REQUEST['rows'];

$form="<center><table>";

for($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++)
{
$form.="<tr>";

for($j = 1; $j <= $clmns; $j++)
{
    $form.="<td><textarea style='background-color:rgb(249,208,191); color:brown; font-weight:bold; border:solid 3px brown;' id=".$i."_".$j." rows=".$rows." cols=20></textarea></td>";
}

$form.="</tr>";

}

$form.="</table></center>";

$form.="<input type=button value=Save onclick=saveData()     />";

echo $form;

?>
```

**home.php**

```
    <html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">

iframe
{
width:800px;
height:500px;
background-color: blue;
border:solid 5px brown;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

var xmlhttp;

function createForm()
{
var clmns=document.getElementById('clmns').value;
var rows=document.getElementById('rows').value;

document.getElementById('dataEntryForm').src="createForm.php?clmns="+clmns+"&rows="+rows;
}

function saveData()
{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

var v1=document.getElementById('1_1').value;
alert(v1);
xmlhttp.open("POST","saveData.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("data="+v1);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {   
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            //document.getElementById('dataEntryForm').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}


function printMe()
{
var x = document.getElementById("dataEntryForm");
var y = x.contentWindow.print();
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<table>

<tr>
<td>Enter Number of Columns Required :</td>
<td><input type="text" id="clmns" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Enter Number of Maximum rows Required :</td>
<td><input type="text" id="rows" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Show Form" onclick="createForm()"/></td>
</tr>

</table>

<br/><br/>

<iframe name="frame1" id="dataEntryForm"></iframe>
<input type=button onclick="printMe()" />


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576851/no-border-on-html-table-when-printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue N-C. I searched a lot on so many sites. After long time, I found that it is a browser who restricts it in such cases. You just have to enable background color printing option. I have worked with Mozilia Firefox. In that follow this steps to print background-color:

File -> Page Setup -> (check the option) Print Background (colours and images)

You will find similar options in other browser as well.

Comment: Thank you very much Abhilash Mandaliya. It worked for me. Thanks a lot man. :)