# Table border missing windows.print javascript

Tags: javascript, printing

Table border are missing while window.print in java script.
this was my javascript code which i used for printing.

```
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;


    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will not output a border because you've not told it to. It's not exactly the same as your issue but this might help to answer your question: [no border on HTML table when printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576851/no-border-on-html-table-when-printing)

You'll need to set some css like `border:1px solid #000;` to the table element to give it a border.